# How to use iteration method with SGD in Encog?

Tags: java, encog

I am using stochastic gradient descent with Adam update to optimise a simple feed forward neural network in Encog (Java). Stochastic gradient descent class provides an `iteration(count)` method to perform a desired number of iterations. However, the documentation does not make clear whether an iteration stands for one epoch (i.e. a weight update after going through all the training data points) or just a weight update based on a single batch.

Moreover, by calling the method `getIteration()`, it turns out that `iteration(count)` is executing twice the number of desired iterations at each step of the while loop.
The error is reproducible by running the following piece of code:

```
// Define network structure
BasicNetwork network = EncogUtility.
    simpleFeedForward(inputSize, numL1Neurons, numL2Neurons, outputSize, true);
network.reset();

// Stochastic Gradient Descent with Adam
final StochasticGradientDescent train = new StochasticGradientDescent(network, trainingSet);
System.out.println("Update rule: " + train.getUpdateRule().toString());
System.out.println("Batch size: " + train.getBatchSize());

// Count the number of iterations per epoch
int iterationsPerEpoch = (int) Math.ceil(trainingSet.size()/ (double) train.getBatchSize());
System.out.println("Iterations per epoch: " + iterationsPerEpoch);

// Training
int epoch = 0;
StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
while (!train.isTrainingDone()) {
   train.iteration(iterationsPerEpoch);
   epoch++;
   line.setLength(0);
   line.append("Epoch #");
   line.append(epoch);
   line.append(", Iteration #");
   line.append(train.getIteration());
   line.append(", Training Error: ");
   line.append(network.calculateError(trainingSet));
   line.append(", Validation Error: ");
   line.append(network.calculateError(validationSet));
   System.out.println(line.toString());
}
train.finishTraining();
```

Why does `getIteration()` return twice the number of iterations specified in `iteration(count)`? Which is the best way to run one epoch every iteration of the while loop?